# Prove that if $A$, $B$ are similar matrices then for every $\lambda$ $\in$ $\mathbb{R}$ the matrices $A-\lambda I$ and $B-\lambda I$ are similar.

Tags: linear-algebra

How do I prove this proposition:

> If $A$, $B$ are similar matrices then for every $\lambda$ $\in$
>   $\mathbb{R}$ the matrices $A-\lambda I$ and $B-\lambda I$ are similar.

Now, from what I was given I know $A = P^{-1} B P$ and $B = PBP^{-1}$, and

I need to show that $A-\lambda I = M^{-1} (B-\lambda I)M$ and I am done.

I can't see how to solve this, I hope someone does,

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why not try $M=P$?

Comment: @carmichael561 Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $M=P$. $\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ $

Comment: I can accept your question only in 4min so you'll need to wait a little ;)

Comment: Don't worry. I didn't work that hard ;)